# Округлить float в Python с точностью до 50 в меньшую сторону

Tags: python, округление

В меньшую сторону - это критично.

Округлить до 50, не до 100.

Вот таким образом:

```
199.99 -> 150 
151.99 -> 150 
159.99 -> 150 
149.99 -> 100 
101.99 -> 100
```

Comment: умножить на два, округлить до  100, разделить на два

Comment: Получается не в меньшую сторону 199.99 > 200 а должно быть 150

Comment: Покажите ваш код, мы поможем.

Comment: 199.99 => 399.98 => 300 => 150

Comment: int(round(n * 2, -2) / 2)

Comment: 199.99 => 399.98 => 400 => 200 вот так получится в вашем примере

Answer (score 3, accepted):

делим на `50` и умножаем на `50`

```
print(199.99 // 50 * 50)
```

```
test = (
    (199.99, 150),
    (151.99, 150),
    (159.99, 150),
    (149.99, 100),
    (101.99, 100),
)

for a, b in test:
    print(a // 50 * 50,  b)
```